# Excel: Formula to calculate the number of days occurring in multiple date ranges for different individuals

Tags: excel

I am trying to develop an Excel formula that allows me to count the number of days occurring within two date ranges for different individuals. Here is a sample of my dataset:

```
    id  admDt       sepDt       admDur  id  dxDt-1      dxDt          admDurTot
    1   16/01/2000  18/01/2000  2       1   24/01/2000  24/02/2000    28
    1   22/01/2000  18/02/2000  27      2   30/03/2000  30/04/2000    0
    1   20/02/2000  22/02/2000  2       3   3/02/2000   3/03/2000     0
    1   24/02/2000  28/02/2000  4       4   31/12/1999  31/01/2000    0
    5   19/05/2000  20/06/2000  32      5   20/05/2000  20/06/2000    31
    8   25/12/1999  28/12/1999  3       6   13/11/2000  13/12/2000    0
    8   18/01/2000  26/01/2000  8       7   14/04/2000  14/05/2000    0
    8   28/01/2000  28/01/2009  3288    8   23/12/1999  23/01/2000    9
                                        9   9/02/2000   9/03/2000     0
```

For columns A-D, each row reflects an event (in this case, a hospital admission):

- `id` = individual's ID number
- `admDt` = date of admission
- `sepDt` = date of discharge
- `admDur` = duration (in days) of admission

**Please note that multiple rows can relate to one individual** (e.g., `A2:E5`).

For columns F-I, each row reflects one individual's data:

- `id` = individual's ID number
- `dxDt-1` = date one month preceding diagnosis
- `dxDt` = date of diagnosis
- `admDurTot` = total duration (in days) of admission

Date ranges for each admission (`admDt` and `sepDt`) and individual (`dxDt-1` and `dxDt`) can be different. While the date ranges for each event may span across months (e.g., cells `A3:C3` or `A9:C9`), I am interested in calculating the number of days the person spent in hospital (`admDurTot`) in the month preceding their diagnosis (`dxDt`). **Please note that the values in** `admDurTot` **reflect those I would like to obtain, rather than those obtained from different formulae I have used**.

I have tried variations of the `SUMIFS` formula:

- =SUMIFS($D:$D, $A:$A, $G2, $B:$B, ">=" & $H2, $C:$C, "<=" & $I2)
- =SUMIFS($D:$D, $A:$A, $G2, $B:$B, "<=" & $I2, $C:$C, ">=" & $H2)
- =SUMIFS($D:$D, $A:$A, $G2, $B:$B, ">=" & $H2, $C:$C, ">" & $H2, $C:$C, "<=" & $I2)

however, they are confounded by the fact that both `admDt` and `sepDt` often fall outside the range of interest (i.e., they are not between `dxDt-1` and `dxDt`). For example, in the case of individual `1`, the above formulae indicate that he spent 33 days in hospital in the month preceding his diagnosis. In reality, he spent 28 days in hospital during that period.

I have found little guidance on other websites. I have reviewed the following link; however, I am not familiar with C#.

[Calculate number of days between two dates separated by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382935/calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates-separated-by-month)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: You solution  with SUMIFS won't work because the value in $D:$D only gives the total days for each admission but what you need to allow for the case where the `dxDt-1` day is within a period of admission.   I would add a helper column to work out the number of days for each admission according to your criteria.   As a pseudo-formula it might look like   `=IF(sepDt <= dxDt-1, 0, if(admDt < dxDt-1, MIN(sepDt,dxDt) - dxDt-1), IF(and(admDt >= dxDt-1,admDt <= dxDt),min(sepDt,dxDt)-admDt),0)))`    but you should have to use VLOOKUP or INDEX(...,MATCH() to get the corresponding dxDtt-1 & dxDT values

Comment: @tjejojyj I ended up analysing my data in R, so didn't follow this up; however, I received an appropriate answer [elsewhere](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/967560-excel-formula-calculate-number-days-occurring-multiple-date-ranges-different-individuals-2.html)